# JQuery UI Tabs using Ajax and Bookmarkable

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, tabs, bookmarks

I use JQuery UI Tabs version 1.10.3. Loaded the pane data using AJAX. I saw a sample of implementing bookmarkable JQuery UI Tabs but it is static tabs (not AJAX loaded), as you can see the sample here http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/tabs/default.html#tabs-2

Tried to find some solution on how to combine AJAX and bookmarkable features but no success. Anyone can help me with any solutions or enlightenment?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

http://muledesign.com/2009/05/bookmarkable-tabs-with-jquery-ui/

This has worked out great for me.

Here is a sample found on the page that is of interest.

http://muledesign.com/demo/tabs/default-tabs.html#comments

He's using a different jquery version but I don't know how much that matters.